# how to use applied cogroup method with functional operation in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, functional-programming

I've tried to solve applied `cogroup` problem. but I really don't know that...

If there are two RDDs with different keys as in the example below, Is it possible to extract valid `data1` only when the first word is the same using `cogroup`?

```
val data1 = sc.parallelize(Seq(("aa", 1), ("ba", 2), ("bc", 2), ("b", 3), ("c", 1)))
val data2 = sc.parallelize(Seq(("a", 3), ("b", 5)))

val cogroupRdd: RDD[(String, (Iterable[Int], Iterable[Int]))] = data1.cogroup(data2)
/* List(
    (ba,(CompactBuffer(2),CompactBuffer())), 
    (bc,(CompactBuffer(2),CompactBuffer())), 
    (a,(CompactBuffer(),CompactBuffer(3))), 
    (b,(CompactBuffer(3),CompactBuffer(5))), 
    (c,(CompactBuffer(1),CompactBuffer())), 
    (aa,(CompactBuffer(1),CompactBuffer()))
) */
```

The result should be `Array(("aa", 1), ("ba", 2), ("bc", 2), ("b", 3))`

I solved this problem by using `broadcast()` as @mrsrinivas said. 
But `broadcast()` is not appropriate for large data.

```
val bcast = sc.broadcast(data2.map(_._1).collect())
val result = data1.filter(r => bcast.value.contains(myFuncOper(r._1)))
```

Is there a method to solve this problem using `cogroup` with the functional operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cogroup` after extracting a key that would match `data2`'s keys, and then use `filter` and `map` to remove values without matches and "restructure" the data:

```
val result: RDD[(String, Int)] = data1
  .keyBy(_._1.substring(0, 1)) // key by first character
  .cogroup(data2)
  .filter { case (_, (_, data2Values)) => data2Values.nonEmpty }
  .flatMap { case (_, (data1Values, _)) => data1Values }
```

Comment: The sort order changes, but it is the answer I wanted.
Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Could you answer one more question? If you don't mind?

If I used `keyBy` for large data, it takes a long time to execute. 
Is there any other alternative?

Comment: I can't see a faster alternative - you'll have to create the key to cogroup by, you can do it with `map` as well but it will take the same amount of time.

Comment: Okay.. Thank you very much!

Comment: @TzachZohar,Hi I'm facing memory issue while using `cogroup` any suggestions and tips would be great-full, as I'm new to spark and don't know how to resolve it. Please find the question here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180307/how-to-use-cogroup-for-large-datasets]

Answer (score 1):

**Short:**

```
val result = data1
  .flatMap(x => x._1.split("").map(y => (y, x)))
  .join(data2)
  .map(x => x._2._1)
  .distinct
```

**Detailed:**

`flatMap(x => x._1.split("").map(y => (y, x)))` holds

```
 List(
  (a, (aa, 1)),
  (a, (aa, 1)),
  (b, (ba, 2)),
  (a, (ba, 2)),
  (b, (bc, 2)),
  (c, (bc, 2)),
  (b, (b, 3)),
  (c, (c, 1))
)
```

after `join(data2)`

```
List(
  (a, ((aa, 1), 3)),
  (a, ((aa, 1), 3)),
  (a, ((ba, 2), 3)),
  (b, ((ba, 2), 5)),
  (b, ((bc, 2), 5)),
  (b, ((b, 3), 5))
)
```

Now all we interested in distinct 2nd first pairs, which can be done by `map(x => x._2._1).distinct`

Comment: Thanks for your reply again!